# Bluemix Cloud Foundry: JAVA_OPTS $PORT is blank

Tags: java, ibm-cloud, cloud-foundry

This is running in IBM Bluemix.

I am running a Java Ninja Framework app, as a standalone jar (which uses embedded Jetty).  If I run it locally:

`$ java -jar -Dninja.port=4444 new-app-1.0.0.jar`

The app starts up, and listens on port 4444: `o.e.jetty.server.ServerConnector - Started ServerConnector@c9d0d6{HTTP/1.1}{0.0.0.0:4444}`

However, this is not working when pushing to CF.

I have tried in the manifest:

```
---
applications:
- path: "./target/new-app-1.0.0.jar"
  memory: "500m"
  name: "foo-new-app"
  env:
    JAVA_OPTS: "-Dninja.port=$PORT"
  buildpack: java_buildpack
```

The app always listens on 8080 (the default):

`OUT 03:25:29.979 [main] INFO  o.e.jetty.server.ServerConnector - Started ServerConnector@65ae6ba4{HTTP/1.1}{0.0.0.0:8080}`

And so the app fails healthcheck, since its listening on the wrong port.

---

Following the suggestions for @sabha I ran

`CF_TRACE=true cf app foo-new-app`

And here is the detected start command:

```
  "detected_start_command":"CALCULATED_MEMORY=$($PWD/.java-buildpack/open_jdk_jre/bin/java-buildpack-memory-calculator-2.0.2_RELEASE -memorySizes=metaspace:64m.. -memoryWeights=heap:75,metaspace:10,native:10,stack:5 -memoryInitials=heap:100%,metaspace:100% -totMemory=$MEMORY_LIMIT) && JAVA_OPTS=\"-Djava.io.tmpdir=$TMPDIR -XX:OnOutOfMemoryError=$PWD/.java-buildpack/open_jdk_jre/bin/killjava.sh $CALCULATED_MEMORY -Dninja.port=\" &&  eval exec $PWD/.java-buildpack/open_jdk_jre/bin/java $JAVA_OPTS -cp $PWD/. ninja.standalone.NinjaJetty"
```

It looks like the `-Dninja.port` arg is not set properly:

`-Dninja.port=\"`

If I look in the bluemix console (Environment Variables), this is what I see for the `JAVA_OPTS` variable:

`-Dninja.port=$PORT`

Is Bluemix not handling this correctly?  I should be able to use $PORT in there, according to the CF docs.

---

Here is where the java_buildpack docs describe using $PORT as argument: https://github.com/cloudfoundry/java-buildpack/blob/master/docs/framework-java_opts.md#escaping-strings

---

Again following @sabha, I ended up using: `JAVA_OPTS="-Dninja.port=\\$PORT"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Appears the $PORT gets interpreted by the buildpack earlier ahead of real execution. Escape the $PORT like this '\$PORT' and the java buildpack just uses it like a literal and the arg gets interpreted in final runtime.

Set this way: **cf set-env foo-new-app JAVA_OPTS ' -Dninja.port=\$PORT' **  && cf restage foo-new-app .

Then check using the methods described above. 
vcap@i7lpc06hav3:~$ ps -ef | grep java
vcap        14     1 69 14:30 ?        00:00:33 /home/vcap/app/.java-buildpack/oracle_jre/bin/java -.......... **-Dninja.port=8080** -Daccess.logging.enabled=false -Dhttp.port=8080  -classpath /home/vcap/app/.java- ... org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap start

Answer (score 1):

In CF Diego, default port assigned is `8080`, so you get the default behavior. You can verify this either by:
1) `cf ssh` to app and `ps -ef` to see the java command line args or
2) restart the app and check the buildpack output for release step or
3) just try `CF_TRACE=true cf app foo-new-app` and check the detected_start_command value.

Comment: Tried your suggestions and updated question.  Mind taking a look?

Comment: Appears the $PORT gets interpreted by the buildpack earlier ahead of real execution. Escape the $PORT like this and the java buildpack just uses it like a literal and the arg gets interpreted in final runtime: